# Android login to blackboard with stored user ID and password

Tags: android, authentication, webview, blackboard

I am trying to write an app that will, among other things, allow me to log in to my school's blackboard page.  I want to be able to log in automatically with the username and password stored by the app and display the page in a WebView.

I have been looking at the Apache HTTP examples, but I'm not familiar with most of this, so I'm very lost.

Would anybody mind pointing me in the right direction on this?  The login page is [here](http://bb.csueastbay.edu/webapps/portal/frameset.jsp).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple JSON parsing example in the documentation for [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html).